How to add/remove an element from a set in Java while iterating
I know there's a way to do it with ListIterator, but I can't find a SetIterator. Is doing something like this even possible?

Did you check the documentation for iterator methods?  A regular Iterator can remove elements.  Since Sets don’t allow manual ordering of elements, it would not make sense to allow an iterator to insert elements.

Have you checked the standard API for Interface Set? It does have an iterator() method that returns an Iterator.

It does have an Iterator, but not a ListIterator which is a different class. An Iterator allows me to remove the current element I'm iterating over, but in my case I want to remove any arbitrary element from my set in O(1) time during my iteration which is the functionality I'm questioning the existence of.

There is no supported way to do that while iterating.

@CodingMike Check the link in the "This question already has answers here" box. If answers there do not help, edit the question to explain why they don't help. When you edit, include information from your previous comment. Including that will clarify the question.
